# Data always appear and updated when move to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a simple add to cart view controller. It contain product you like to order, and the product list updated when user add another product so I Use `viewWillAppear`. I use table view to store product list

and I have sub total price label. The value is from all product price summed

but when I move to another `viewController` and go back to add to cart view controller, the price summed again.

simply, I want to make if the user didn't add or remove product. The sub total label value didn't changed.

Comment: Well, as you're using `viewWillAppear` to update the list, it will obviously update whenever the view appears. Perhaps you could show us the code where you update the value and we can help you find a better solution.

Comment: Is your viewController always instanced ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Solved it by changed the value back to 0 before viewWillAppear

so i have function to calculate sub total like this

```
func theTotal(){
    subTotal = 0 //here
    grandTotal = 0 //here
    for i in 0 ..< cartMenu.count {
        let isiDishes = cartMenu[i]
        subTotal += isiDishes.price
        subTotalLabel.text = "Rp. \(subTotal)"
        hargaAwal = subTotal
    }
    grandTotal = subTotal + tax + deliveryFee
    grandTotalLabel.text = "Rp. \(grandTotal)"
}
```

and in my viewWillAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    cartMenu = realm.objects(Dishes)
    if session != 0 {
        if cartMenu.isEmpty {
            print("EMPTY")
        } else {
            datePickerView.hidden = true
            viewErrorLogin.hidden = true
            tableView.reloadData()
            buttonAddress.setTitle(dataButton, forState: .Normal)
            secondButtonAddress.setTitle(secondDataButton, forState: .Normal)
                theTotal() //here
            deliveryFeeData()
            taxData()
        }
    } else {
        viewErrorLogin.hidden = false
    }
}
```

I reset the value sub total, so in the beginning the formula is also reset. And the value sub total is calculating back like nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Move your code block to viewDidLoad method. Then that code block will not call every time your view appear. It's only called when the view load

[iOS Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad)